# Retrieve numbers separated by '-'

Tags: java, regex

Lets say I have a large amount of (random) text. Within this text there is a phone number, consisting of three digits, a dash, another three digits, a dash, and four digits. For example, XXX-XXX-XXXX. What would be the regex for retrieving this number from the text. I tried using:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(previousText);
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(".*(\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d).*")
Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(currentText);
```

Now, I though it would work, but it doesn't. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex: `\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`

Comment: @instanceofTom I can't give more details. I only know regex, not Java :).

Comment: You have '//' instead of '\\'

Comment: Sorry, was trying to type and hit return too fast.  Perhaps it's a bit of confusion around scoping, but probably izb is right, your example is using the wrong slashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String number = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(number);
}
```